# Linux DC++ command line app

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, dc++

I am looking for a command line dc++ client for Ubuntu 9.10 server 32bit.

Apps I have tried so far:

- nanodc - Can't compile
- microdc2 - Installs but users can't download from me when using this
- ldcc - Can't compile problems with Turbo Vision , can't seem to find the header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so as it turns out after getting microdc2 installed correctly it does work , it just takes alot longer to hash files which is why i originally thought it was not working.

You also need to start it up with a refresh interval so that it can update itself when new files are added to a common folder its monitoring

Answer (score 0):

[There used to be a dc++ plugin for weechat](http://wiki.flashtux.org/wiki/WeeChat/dc)

The link to the original git repo seems to be dead, but the author of weechat was planning to host a mirror on his site. Best way is to catch him on freenode and ask about it if you fail to find the source code yourself.

Also, [headless mode is planned for eiskaltdc](http://code.google.com/p/eiskaltdc/issues/detail?id=971).